# Add GUI Designer JPanel to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

I have a class extending `JPanel` in NetBeans. The class is working with the "form designer", where you can just drag and drop GUI elements on the screen. I have another class extending `JFrame` that is creating an instance of this class and adding it to its content frame.

`JPanel` class:

```
/**
 * Creates new form OpenPanel
 */
public OpenPanel() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 48)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("Jungle Tracks");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(87, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addGap(86, 86, 86))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(21, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addGap(20, 20, 20))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 225, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
}// </editor-fold>

// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

The main `JFrame` class (into which I'm trying to add the JPanel), is as follows:

```
public class MainClass extends JFrame {

static final int WIDTH = 800;
static final int HEIGHT = 600;

public MainClass() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException, BackingStoreException {
    super("MainClass");

    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    OpenPanel open = new OpenPanel();
    ((OpenPanel)open).setFocusable(true);

            getContentPane().add(open);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);              
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException, BackingStoreException {
    MainClass mc = new MainClass();
}

}
```

But the JPanel and it's UI elements created in NetBean's design view aren't shown, or to my knowledge--even added to the `JFrame`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"I have a class extending JPanel .. another class extending JFrame.."*  Don't extend either unless adding functionality.  Just use an instance and add components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that your `paint(...)` method does not call the `super.paint(...)` method within it, and so the JPanel is not painting its own components well. If this is so, then I suggest:

- Don't override `paint(...)` as this is rarely needed, and if done, must be done with care since this method is responsible for painting not only the component but also its borders and *its child components* -- the very problem you seem to be running into.
- Instead override `paintComponent(...)` but be sure to call the `super.paintComponent(...)` in this method, usually as the very first line of the method.